# Write a program that always outputs "2012" - even if it's modified!

Tags: popularity-contest, source-layout, radiation-hardening

This idea is not mine, though I don't know where it originated. I once met it in a programming contest very long ago (1998, if I remember correctly). The task is to write a program in your favorite language that outputs `2012` **and only** `2012`. The catch is that the program must still output `2012` after any **one** of its characters is modified. The modification can be either insertion, deletion or replacement. Of course, the modification will be such that the program is still syntactically valid.

Since I don't know all the programming languages, I have to ask the audience to help me and test the answers submitted.

**Added:** Many have commented that my definition of acceptable modifications is too vague. Here's my second attempt: **The allowed modifications will leave your program syntactically valid and will not cause it to crash.** There, I think that should cover all the compile-time, link-time and run-time errors. Though I'm sure that there will be some odd edge case in some language anyway, so when that comes up we'll look at it individually.

Comment: How about runtime errors like reading a most likely invalid address?

Comment: @PeterTaylor - There are 3 answers already, the C one with heavy revising. You can look for inspiration there.

Comment: @eBusiness - Slippery slope. For an interpreted language syntax errors can also be "runtime errors". However I'm on the side of the contestant. Runtime errors are also disallowed (that is, the changed character will not make those).

Comment: @Vilx-: Adding link-time errors to that list might be useful as well. ;)

Comment: **Hint:** In theory, your code should have 2012 written twice. :)

Comment: @muntoo: You're going to have to prove that; I can't see the number of "2012"s going below 3.

Comment: You need not write 2012 even once, just write 2011+1 instead.  I donno if you could encode 2012 as a series of mathematical operations so that 2012 isn't ever even "encoded twice".

Comment: Anyone figured out if this is impossible in APL or GolfScript or similarly terse?

Comment: This has got me thinking about DNA and redundancy and the potential for cosmic rays to flip bits in my programs. Interesting stuff.

Comment: ... You need some sleep.

Comment: @Vilx- Not until I finish listening to Dream Theater! (But yeah... [GMT-8:00].)

Comment: @muntoo: And I'm saying that you need at least 3. Even if 3 is bigger than 2, "at least" implies that it is doable *at least*. In any case, one could get cute and say "you only need 2011+1" or similar, but that's besides the point, and not likely helpful in code golf, in any case.

Comment: Well... actually... this wasn't really meant as a golf... but seems like people enjoy doing that, so have fun! :)

Comment: @Vilx-: Now you tell me. :P

Comment: Well, I didn't really mention the word "golf" anywhere, did I? XD

Comment: @Vilx-: Indeed.

Comment: The original version where the program had to output `2012` was interesting, but now that you also allow for the program to **crash**, it’s much less interesting.

Comment: @timwi.  I think you misread it, it's *not* allowed to crash.  Also, if a modification causes the program to print/echo 2012 **twice** does it fail?

Comment: @mellamokb: The question as phrased clearly allows programs in which a single-character modification may make it compile and then crash.

Comment: From OP (in Added section): **The allowed modifications will leave your program syntactically valid and will not cause it to crash.**  I read that as you can't crash it with your one-character modification.  However that was a clarification to the question that probably wasn't present when you wrote your previous comment :)

Comment: Actually it was already present when he wrote the previous comment, and yes, that's exactly what I mean - you don't have to worry that the modification will make your program crash. Or even cause it to behave in an "undefined way" (which is often the case with C/C++).

Comment: @Vilx-, how much output is allowed? `20122012` would work for PHP/HTML. Does `2012` just need to appear in the output, or should it be the *only* output?

Comment: @zzzzBov - it has to be the ONLY output. Just the 4 characters "2012" - no more, no less.

Comment: I've make a python script to judge all the python solutions. The script breaks the first and the third python solutions, with many different methods. <s>And the second solution use lambda to guard itself, is unbreakable.</s> The second python solution is in python 3. I modified it into python 2 format and then judge program broke it. Here is the judge script. <!-- language: lang-python --> from StringIO import StringIO import sys def run(prog, atexp=True): stdout = sys.stdout fakeOut = StringIO() try: sys.stdout = fakeOut # exec prog # running exec directly will break some solutions by mistake

Comment: I think this is where you get most of your rep... (right now +488)

Comment: @EriktheGolfer - Umm, ok?

Comment: @Vilx- I mean, this is the post that has granted you most of your rep points. If you made this post CW, you will entirely transform to an almost-low-rep user. (Don't do it)

Comment: @EriktheGolfer - I don't have a button to do that anyway. :) Also, I don't care much about rep.

Comment: It's funny how everyone instinctively puts the program size in their answer even though this is not code golf.

Comment: I worked pretty hard to make this work in my fungoid esolang, but as `;` (terminate with no output) could be inserted (or replace) just about anywhere and having to detect that (and not produce doubled output) was basically impossible. eg. if `>"2012"@` prints correctly (and assume partially hardened), then `>;"2012"@` prints nothing. `>">"2012"@"...` with `...` being some kind of validation check would catch a similarly inserted semicolon...but it would *also* detect most other changes and output `20122012`. Oof.

Comment: Would a proof that this task is impossible in some language be a valid submission?

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya - Well, it's not what I had in mind, but why not? It's certainly on topic as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

## C, 53 characters

```
main(){register*a="2012";(puts("2012"==a?a:"2012"));}
```

A bit longer than the scripting language answers, and follows the same basic principle. Relies on the fact that due to the constraints of C's syntax, the only letters that would be possible to change without making the program invalid are within the strings!

**Edit:** Shaved off 4 characters.

**Reedit:** Robustness increased, shaved off one character.

**Re-redit:** Longer, but more robust. Just try your `&` now! (Correctly this time).

**Update:** Shortened a bit; defeats most approaches seen so far.

<del>**Update:** Changed int to void; should defeat the last possible approach to break it I can think of.</del>

<del>**Update:** I thunk of another approach; replacing the last `a` (may it rot) with `0`; using two-letter names should deal with that problem.</del>

**Update:** Last update revoked; assuming changes causing runtime errors are disallowed; `a` will work just fine.

**Update:** Backtracking some more; attempting to dereference `*a` will also segfault; so using `void` to tease a compile error out of it should not be necessary.

**Update:** And a final shortening; that relies on the string `"2012"` being placed at but one address (which is common); and that literal strings are read-only (also common).

**Update:** It cost me two characters, but I defeated your puny semi-colon!

Comment: main(){int a="2012";puts(strcmp(a,"2012")?"2012":&a);}

Comment: @M.Joanis: Excellent point; addressed. :)

Comment: `1-a` instead of the last `-a` gives output `012`.

Comment: @Howard: That last a is nothing but trouble, no matter how I phrase it. :P

Comment: Out of interest, why `register int` ?

Comment: @PaulR: Good point.

Comment: @PaulR: Now changed to `register void`; The `register` is there to prevent `&`; the `void` is there to prevent `*`.

Comment: I can still put a `!` before the last `st`, although that causes a runtime error on my VC++2008, so I guess it don't count. Not sure what the `puts()` should do according to the C standard.

Comment: @Vilx-: Putting a `!` before the last `st` returns `0`; which is `NULL`; and any attempt to dereference that should quite rightly give a segmentation fault. `puts()` needs to dereference the pointer to do it's thing, so it's well-behaved.

Comment: Well, I expected that. Though it's also feasible (intuitive) that it could have detected the special case of NULL and output nothing. But you're right.

Comment: @Vilx-: C doesn't really "do" special cases; especially not of `NULL`. ;)

Comment: Now a small mistake: you have to invert the ternary otherwise you may just change the literal string.

Comment: main(){register*a="2012";puts("2012"==a?&a:"2012");} This doesn't work on ideone, but it works on my cygwin installation. Hm.

Comment: @Howard: Did that. :)

Comment: @M.Joanis: Hate to break it to you, but the cygwin is wrong: Using `&` with a register variable is explicitly verboten by the standard.

Comment: @WillihamTotland: Yeah, it doesn't make any sense... I'm just suprized it works the exact same way it did when I compiled de version in my very first comment above. /me sad @ cygwin

Comment: @M.Joanis: It's understandable, tho'; what the cygwin compiler is doing is probably treating the `register` keyword as `auto`; which in and of itself isn't all that terrible; most compilers probably that anyway. The issue is that it imbues register with the semantics of auto; and forgets that while *most* other compilers might deal with it like that; that doesn't make it any more right.

Comment: Using `"2012"-=a` or `"2012"=-a` results in UB.

Comment: @muntoo: Getting compile errors for both of those from where I'm sitting.

Comment: OK... correct me if this is invalid C, but it just worked on my VS2010. Insert a `;` between `puts` and `(`.

Comment: @Vilx-: That is indeed correct and legal. Attempting to defeat it as we speak.

Comment: @Vilx-: And it's defeated. :)

Comment: Arrrrgh! \*Returns to the shadows to plot his revenge\*

Comment: How about using a comma instead of a semicolon?

Comment: @PeterTaylor That gives me a compiler error.

Comment: +1, Congratulations, I think you've nailed it.  I wrote a simple test harness that tried to compile and run every possible one-char variation of your code, and every single one of them either did not compile, crashed or printed `2012`!  (I only used printable ASCII characters for the insertion and substitution tests, but I doubt expanding the repertoire would help.)

Comment: Wow... awesome... This will highly likely be the accepted answer, but I'll wait a while before accepting so that people don't lose interest.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Heh, that's a lot of effort; thanks for going through all that. :)

Comment: `putc` ruins the show.

Comment: @Fors: In my test, making puts putc throws a compile error.

Comment: When I compile it using Clang and GCC it doesn't throw a compile error, but it does using ICC (but then ICC throws an error on `main(){putc(48);}` as well).

Comment: I guess that in the end it is odd that Clang and GCC accepts `putc(a)`. Oh well, `putc` as least ruins the show using Clang or GCC, as they are showing some odd behaviour.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You should mention which compiler (and compiler settings) you used. For example, this program is easily invalidated on a compiler that doesn't merge string literals, so that `"2012"==a` is false and the output can be changed by changing the last string literal. I think replacing the last `"2012"` by `1 ? "2012" : "2012"` would fix that.

Comment: `putc` requires a stream as second parameter; as does `fputs`. But what about `"2012"!=a`?

Comment: @Titus: If you mean switching `==` for `!=` in the ternary, that gets you nowhere; instead of outputting `a` it now outputs `"2012"`.

Comment: Some env. `main(){register*a="2012";(puts("2012"==a?0:"2012"));}` print nothing

Answer (score 38):

### Haskell, 19

```
(\xx@2012->xx)$2012
```

or, as a full program,

### 29

```
main=print$(\xx@2012->xx)2012
```

---

For a bit more fun:

```
(\l@(_:_:t:[])->t:l)['0'..'2']
```

---

To get one that can't be modified in such a way that yields merely a runtime error, we can encode the information in the lengths of lists which can't be modified using just one-character-changes, i.e.

```
map(head.show.length)[[(),()],[],[()],[(),()]]
```

To make it more modifiable (safely), we can also use the number itself as list element – just need to make it strings to prevent exchanging commas for plus':

```
map(head.show.length)[["2012","2012"],[],["2012"],["2012","2012"]]
```

As this string is just the result of the expression, we can also again substitute it with that – not a problem thanks to Haskell's lazyness

### <del>64</del> 72

```
a=map(head.show.length.init)[[a,a,a],[a],[a,a],[a,a,a]]
main=putStrLn a
```

The `init` acts as "minus one, but non-negative" here.

---

We can also include the type system in the redundancy scheme and then write the number in a way that *could* be modified with one-character changes...

```
u :: Enum a => (a,[b])->(a,b)
u(a,[b]) = (succ a , b)
p :: (a,b)->(a,[b])
p(a,b) = (a,[b])

ι :: (Int,())           -- Integral type to make sure you can't make it 0/0
ι = (\n -> (n-n,()))0

twothousandandtwelve = map(head.show.fst) [ u.p.u.p$ι , ι , u.p$ι , u.p.u.p$ι ]
```

(`GHCi> twothousandandtwelve` ≡> `"2012"`)

You could now change any one `u` to `p` vice versa, but that would always mess up the deepness of list stackings in the second tuple element and thereby trigger a compile-time error.

This idea could be expanded further in such a way that whole texts could be encoded compactly, easy to read and edit, and still safe from modifing single characters.

---

And yet another one...

```
main = print N2012
data Counter = Τv |Πy |Υj |Cε |Ho |Φϑ |Ωm |Sg |Πl |Pt |Yϑ |Γσ |Km |Φz |Εα |Av |Ζρ |Ηρ |Εv |Κs |Rζ |Γϑ |Οc |Dι |Rυ |Λd |Bγ |Wt |Xε |Ωη |Ιa |Hζ |Ed |Qj |Wπ |Κw |Qu |Γο |Oι |Mσ |Ωκ |Yg |Kυ |Aj |Du |Λζ |Nζ |Θτ |Pε |Yf |Βa |Τγ |Qx |Jη |Pδ |Iq |Ωn |Fv |Kl |Ψη |Δj |Θσ |Hd |Θq |Υs |Ht |Fρ |Jh |Lζ |Hμ |Υι |Ρζ |Ρv |Dυ |Wo |Iχ |Iζ |Γy |Kr |Sσ |Iμ |Μο |Xw |Εμ |Cσ |Yξ |Aq |Jf |Hσ |Oq |Hq |Nυ |Lo |Jκ |Ρz |Οk |Θi |Θα |Αη |Gh |Lξ |Jm |Ων |Zu |Μc |Qη |Κγ |Αψ |Χζ |Hρ |Γρ |Uϑ |Rj |Χγ |Rw |Mω |Πζ |Θρ |Ωd |Υh |Nt |Tη |Qψ |Θω |Εχ |Iw |Σx |Ηn |Mτ |Xt |Yx |Φε |Hh |Wη |Mf |Ψχ |Νγ |Βξ |Aϑ |Qp |Τϑ |Φm |Uy |Gy |Cd |Bχ |Λl |Οτ |Εa |Df |Li |Aι |Yi |Νκ |Vc |Γx |Φρ |Φp |Nξ |Kf |Tw |Λξ |Φn |Λa |Oψ |Υχ |Fψ |Xω |Τq |Οσ |Σj |Θψ |Το |Νr |Ιπ |Τi |Dτ |Φf |Μn |Χm |Ηε |Wa |Αχ |Uδ |Λf |Ρu |Qk |Wα |Uρ |Τζ |Lg |Qy |Τν |Jϑ |Βδ |Mε |Μι |Πβ |Bη |Eκ |Κz |Ηh |Fδ |Σp |Εγ |Qφ |Μτ |Νχ |Ψν |Pw |Χz |Εϑ |We |Nπ |Tυ |Wg |Bh |Tρ |Ζν |Λm |Ag |Dσ |Πι
                |Oη |Nν |Χl |Χp |Sξ |Πt |Οϑ |Wο |Yη |Cp |Tm |Ξs |Εβ |Ιb |Ρρ |Fs |Um |Ep |Jλ |Rρ |Ρξ |Ua |Οq |Γξ |Zη |Nη |Qτ |Nc |Ez |Xσ |Yφ |Ρy |Yε |Ετ |Φκ |Λω |Ωα |Μκ |Φw |Mt |Tk |Sf |Ηξ |Οb |Νπ |Κε |Mι |Kz |Vi |Ξx |Ψs |Αο |Qδ |Kt |Aσ |Οm |Ψδ |Λγ |Ακ |Hα |Wϑ |Τμ |Γγ |Jδ |Ικ |Ηϑ |Μp |Zo |Κn |Qz |Δe |Pe |Jο |Qι |Tu |Jν |Ξμ |Πω |Αm |Θw |Nε |Dy |Zξ |Υα |Dβ |Hο |Χv |Gr |Ωl |Jb |Σl |Vζ |Ξ  |Nx |Qs |Βh |Qg |Νx |Co |Rσ |Νυ |Χg |Ρt |Wy |Ηκ |Οa |Yμ |Uj |Uξ |Op |Μr |Ζα |Ξw |Mυ |Ar |Ργ |Zζ |Sv |Vy |Βo |Κι |Vϑ |Ξι |Uζ |Fμ |Su |Ιξ |Fϑ |Hi |Hw |Mv |Χχ |Θg |Sν |Pp |Mπ |Pk |Bκ |Lυ |Ρλ |Ιr |Uλ |Νo |Κο |Nh |Lε |Sw |Ξλ |Zυ |Mr |Bv |Κπ |Aγ |Dv |Pd |Ξσ |Μg |Oπ |Χξ |Nj |Kψ |Ξπ |Mκ |Gn |Ωe |Gγ |Pν |Yz |Nl |Οο |Ic |Pz |Ξf |Νω |Υμ |Ηq |Nw |Θm |Μx |Jε |Φy |Οz |Ξz |Ti |Οψ |Φγ |Tψ |Oγ |Zϑ |Ιk |Σw |Rf |Υi |Ωp |Vr |Υτ |Xl |Οβ |Πb |Δν |Οu |Jα |Ττ |Κl |Pf |Iκ |Gk |Πe |Σu |Δβ |Ωh |Nλ |Ξt |My |Πs |Βr |Mγ |Δω |Le |Zρ |Θv |Σs |Ηd |
               Bn |Κu |Δξ |Pτ |Ηα |Δu |Πμ |Ρh |Bω |Τλ |Gt |Αρ |Sh |Aο |Θδ |Δπ |Wq |Tφ |Γo |Γf |Λβ |Xυ |Mη |Δw |Qυ |Vν |Βτ |Γα |Μm |Μπ |Κζ |Θd |Fε |Ρτ |Οn |Αs |Wu |Ξh |Μz |Αν |Aε |Yq |Τε |Cz |Ωu |Ec |Ds |Wρ |Θϑ |Κp |Τδ |Mδ |Ηy |Go |Sb |Rξ |Σϑ |Yο |Jg |Vh |Kσ |Nδ |Ηψ |Γh |Rk |Eο |Μk |Ζk |Ψο |Ψμ |Zσ |Pβ |Ρd |Us |Hυ |Βi |Mχ |Σr |Βι |Sχ |Zγ |Δα |Sτ |Γp |Ns |Sn |Νn |Pξ |Νa |Sω |Σi |Τφ |Xο |Eδ |Ba |To |Vj |Sl |Κκ |Δh |Τχ |Gυ |Ρϑ |Bs |Dh |Μσ |Vd |Iϑ |Kg |Νμ |Dμ |Σγ |Πg |Γg |Εt |Fa |Ψn |Ρx |Αj |Mβ |Kλ |Ξψ |Fω |Qζ |Θj |Kπ |Gf |Oe |Yυ |Κk |Wω |Bδ |Lο |Cβ |Nf |Ol |Σo |Fn |Τβ |Βω |Dn |Ha |Πλ |Ss |Σy |Kϑ |Lp |Dδ |Dψ |Ωo |Xγ |Χk |Ωσ |Δa |Sκ |Jμ |Κt |Rc |Ηc |Lχ |Oε |Μλ |Cs |Il |Tι |Ra |Zα |Ωr |Ob |Wβ |Ον |Γν |St |Xλ |Kv |No |Rε |Kd |Mν |Np |Ωc |Δζ |Nβ |Zπ |Ok |Vι |Tδ |Vδ |Γz |Χα |Μs |Βυ |Xc |Xo |Vp |Γχ |Υf |Θπ |Πj |Pi |Γj |By |Φk |Υq |Ny |Rο |Γd |Ωj |Αy |Εo |Κy |Uc |Rm |Ph |Αδ |Ιl |Ιx |Δτ |Zt |Nq |Ct |Φi |Uv |Eπ
                |Κm |Rλ |Vu |Χσ |Τn |Μe |Φη |Ξβ |Εz |Σω |Bb |Ψε |Sε |Ρm |Δο |Vξ |Φo |Ωε |Zb |Σc |Dζ |Ξp |Rη |Ιψ |Δσ |Χη |Kj |Eμ |Qν |Ri |Ip |La |Νξ |Αγ |As |Nr |Δi |Oν |Ζx |Xκ |Pr |Ελ |Λb |Ψk |Ωβ |Pl |Ιy |Cμ |Ζc |Αg |Σρ |Dw |Ρq |Ιη |Pζ |Σa |Uq |Ρμ |Lω |Fh |Ζδ |Αd |Cψ |Κσ |It |Qκ |Fν |Αb |Ηg |Ιν |Ls |Jr |Ow |Je |Zx |Ld |Jl |Ζd |Μo |Χτ |Kα |Μβ |Mo |Σλ |Xρ |Μq |Ψb |Νd |Ρβ |Wδ |Μf |Κρ |Ηb |Ξτ |Qα |Λv |Zψ |Φt |Sδ |Εh |Rκ |Rμ |Χι |Κυ |Ηj |Pχ |Pη |Jσ |Ρσ |Ιχ |Kζ |Εδ |Nω |Iψ |Γμ |Vσ |Ψρ |Χυ |Αw |Kn |Al |Gj |Zj |Αc |Aζ |Ζi |Bz |Vπ |Πw |Αu |Qf |Bf |Ξo |Ρε |Λy |En |Ey |Wi |Σχ |Τc |Dχ |Fg |Ρo |Zm |Ψω |Fq |Μa |Ηt |Wc |Kε |Κτ |Χψ |Κβ |Λφ |Κq |Υm |Πx |Pj |Mi |Δy |Κχ |Lϑ |Wτ |Lη |Nd |Ωk |Iπ |Tα |Bο |Uε |Lc |Rp |Θx |Ρη |Lu |Μζ |Εd |Gρ |Χμ |Vγ |Ιζ |Πυ |El |Uk |Hc |Ξξ |Λx |Ιο |Μy |Ζm |Jw |Iε |Σφ |Αk |Σf |Ac |Ab |Αq |Δf |Θκ |Υa |Ζτ |Jc |Xμ |Sι |Κv |Ζj |Ει |Oω |Ηδ |Φv |Dα |Fτ |Ko |Et |Ψζ |Jx |Mk |Th |Βλ |Λχ |Οo |Υπ |
               Cζ |Θy |Λk |Γδ |Iυ |Σξ |Υϑ |Cι |Cχ |Εσ |Βψ |Iα |Τη |Eυ |Lφ |Lδ |Υw |Ξο |Uσ |Δb |Nϑ |Ζγ |Δz |Cο |Mb |Ξy |Γυ |Εk |Αζ |Vα |Τυ |Ιω |Wυ |Cτ |Ιγ |Yω |Ωy |Ηp |Ψψ |Ah |Dq |Βv |Ιw |Ox |Ξv |Οζ |Tχ |Πψ |Qb |Rδ |Aψ |Zμ |Ζg |Ψφ |Nφ |Δρ |Χe |Vχ |Ηυ |Ml |Σσ |Ζμ |Sz |Πκ |Sγ |Kq |Dη |Υk |Dt |Ξe |Sc |Νs |Μv |Ev |Ji |Rχ |Xπ |Αo |Lμ |Gδ |Fσ |Λϑ |Λe |Σb |Id |Hb |Γι |Βz |Sβ |Tg |Ζο |Δk |Dl |Λσ |Κϑ |Aw |Uγ |Lx |Uψ |Hs |Ωχ |Δφ |Wσ |Π  |Εe |Ro |Λο |Ud |Fχ |Δψ |Νh |Θμ |Zd |Kb |Οδ |Ex |Να |Φσ |Φω |Pm |Λυ |Xq |Si |Σδ |Gα |Bu |Βw |Eχ |Ρι |Gβ |Vο |Yh |Σε |Χq |Hι |Re |Zχ |Ζp |Eρ |Ωγ |Bξ |Hδ |Oξ |Γc |Μγ |Wφ |Πη |Wj |Ιq |Γs |Πο |Κj |Un |Rι |Dφ |Τl |Ωz |Pμ |Wr |Gω |Gi |Εu |Σq |Ρl |Iν |Zy |Rb |Νk |Ky |Uκ |Ησ |Hy |Ir |Tp |Εc |Bw |Εο |Cm |Εw |Ψf |Yχ |Ιρ |Hβ |Ιz |Vλ |Εj |Oδ |Qρ |Θν |Aρ |Ov |Zω |Gψ |Ij |Ξη |Ps |Φh |Οg |Dp |Ta |Ty |Οe |Uο |Rγ |Οr |Θp |Hλ |Νι |Vk |Νz |Tl |Ψi |Λs |Hη |Ζκ |Rz |Hx |Fξ |Ξn |Φe |Sπ |Ηw |Dκ |Ζω
                |Sr |Vψ |Ντ |Vω |Lv |Νg |Fκ |Jψ |Ζs |Oβ |Υζ |Δg |Fυ |Yκ |Χd |Zf |Φμ |Lt |Ξd |Oφ |Τp |Κh |Ψx |Vυ |Qπ |Θφ |Nψ |Ρχ |Rx |Υz |Ξκ |Ξχ |Qn |Pu |Υψ |Az |Xj |Σd |Φξ |Ws |Xα |Βm |Βf |Lh |Hv |Aω |Hν |Kχ |Ρψ |Aδ |Χx |Sη |Φx |Cκ |Jz |Dr |Xu |Ηζ |Ξζ |Gτ |Ca |Af |Aν |Bι |Mc |Ψg |Ωv |Ωs |Qω |Mψ |Lλ |Μα |Kμ |Vl |Yσ |Οι |Ve |Dν |Eg |Ιυ |Xι |Zν |Xϑ |Νζ |Ni |Sφ |Se |Ζa |Xδ |Νv |Wι |Jv |Jt |Ιh |Υv |Cη |Τd |Ψι |Τu |Ge |Πc |Bυ |Mϑ |Χλ |Δλ |Σψ |Μϑ |Απ |Vg |Κα |Sψ |Ζz |Λδ |Aκ |Λκ |Ga |Κb |Db |Jo |Τa |Fw |Τs |Βϑ |Eτ |Wk |Ξu |Ψl |Αι |Νψ |Δι |Qμ |Υn |Bτ |Ηs |Yw |Ye |Iο |Dο |Γe |Rβ |Qv |Xs |Ηη |Yo |Χj |Dω |Οπ |Uβ |Mλ |Qh |Fο |Βd |Ζr |Οv |Zφ |Αi |Dλ |Pb |Οx |Rv |Uz |Εν |Ψτ |Na |Aη |Βu |Ιd |Ηm |Υd |Wn |Qσ |Οp |Αr |Ηλ |Σι |Br |Cu |Ωζ |Θγ |Qo |Bρ |Bψ |Zβ |Πφ |Ρκ |Qϑ |Bj |Vε |Zz |Ζϑ |Za |Θt |Τψ |Ρο |Jq |Πf |Jφ |Τα |Xχ |Χn |Vo |Αt |Bg |Gs |Bi |Rϑ |Nι |Ρa |Υr |Υν |Λo |Γφ |Δo |Yρ |Χc |Ξα |Gq |Γm |Ωμ |Ζυ |Wζ |At |Mw |
               Cf |Επ |Fo |Οh |Tσ |Ηv |Sα |Ζq |Dk |Jπ |Ιm |Mj |Oi |Ψa |Qγ |Rn |Dξ |De |Γk |Ψm |Lα |Cl |Θο |Γq |Λc |Tx |Nm |Ki |Υο |Χr |Φs |Κi |Φλ |Vq |Αω |Ch |Tμ |Xb |Ζπ |Ym |Ζn |Eω |Ξj |Υκ |Τg |Uo |Ai |Sy |Τe |Ητ |Tτ |Λg |Bp |Δq |Χo |Pπ |Dγ |Δγ |Yπ |Ys |Ωδ |Ψσ |Sζ |Πξ |Rφ |Hj |Uf |Td |Ξk |Xψ |Οj |Cx |Φπ |Gλ |Φδ |Ej |Yψ |Ae |Φφ |Jγ |Qχ |Ξγ |Δp |Σg |Is |Eσ |Λπ |Cδ |Ιe |Cυ |Oh |Hm |Tb |Qi |Οl |Bε |Eψ |Hn |Ja |Σν |Γr |Ηu |Ζξ |Ζb |Nu |Θξ |Κd |Qο |Lq |Λw |Ηf |Kξ |Ευ |Rr |Τm |Εξ |Ψp |Χh |Ξi |Fπ |Μφ |Fu |Cξ |Aα |Pγ |Sk |Cω |Ηr |Αp |Ββ |Bx |Fp |Tζ |Pω |Λp |Lm |Jp |Bl |Φc |Vf |Τz |Εy |Λμ |Rd |Νf |Πρ |Ηx |Μψ |Γη |Bα |Συ |Iσ |Γt |Κξ |Io |Ζφ |Γl |Θf |Γλ |Υγ |Ψh |Xg |Tn |Iu |Bφ |Πχ |Λq |Χπ |Bϑ |Εm |Κφ |Λt |Ιu |Ρs |Ιβ |Ωg |Yν |Lσ |Ζι |Eι |Aτ |Φa |Pα |Θz |Ψκ |Θs |Θη |Ηl |Φζ |Bt |Ρυ |On |Ξε |Tf |Gp |Mα |Μi |Kβ |Σο |Ωξ |Νl |Iz |Fk |Dj |Bπ |Nz |Xr |Mp |Χω |Sϑ |Hu |Αμ |Js |Βn |If |Τw |Ηz |Σz |Po |Yj |Ημ |Yβ |Σm |Do
                |Ηχ |Κg |Θo |Ζh |Ψj |Ψu |Ωφ |Δμ |Γa |Bν |Ιε |Oz |Νq |Υp |Qλ |Υc |Υy |Kc |Kh |Ew |Wγ |Νβ |Ωλ |Οξ |Zι |Yr |Sυ |Γπ |Bm |Μj |Pa |Os |Χδ |Κδ |Εx |Iγ |Eη |Fλ |Tγ |Yλ |Hξ |Φq |Τξ |Ql |Δn |Zn |Ot |Sa |Φψ |Nμ |Ξr |Ξc |Φj |Gl |Oλ |Rπ |Am |Mο |Gx |Fd |Cg |Χu |Lι |Wv |Ζt |Jυ |Pσ |Σκ |Wκ |Pv |Ιg |Ωι |Δx |Φl |Eb |Δυ |Cr |Nχ |Ογ |Νφ |Gu |Ασ |Λi |Rτ |Eh |Xη |Md |Wm |Tt |Πα |Υe |Βk |Ju |Dρ |Χβ |Οs |Γi |Kι |Κe |Mm |Χf |Oκ |Vb |Γβ |Οy |Vv |Νϑ |Hl |Λα |Wξ |Om |Βφ |Ρp |Φβ |Βb |Αυ |Υδ |Χφ |Pλ |Νρ |Υλ |Ul |Kγ |Qc |Νm |Πz |Hφ |Es |Ψπ |Xm |Xξ |Tν |Eλ |Ao |Ak |Ka |Ζη |Xk |Γψ |Βπ |Fβ |Βρ |Xx |Βζ |Iτ |Pϑ |Εb |Ψγ |Τk |Gm |Yn |Xν |Νu |Hϑ |Εr |Τπ |Uw |Mh |Og |Μυ |Tj |Λν |Qm |Xn |Ην |Νi |Kη |Zv |Ιι |Ση |Yk |Dx |Aχ |Ou |Fy |Cα |Θl |Γκ |Ax |Vκ |Cn |Cλ |Ξϑ |Wε |Υl |Ψt |Ωa |Θe |Ξω |Ηo |Ll |Bζ |Kw |Αβ |Δc |Oυ |Βj |Jβ |Νε |Eϑ |Ξg |Tz |Cc |Ry |Sρ |Ψz |Yα |Pq |Υg |Jn |Vμ |Σk |Ck |Ωt |Zg |Pι |Hω |Λλ |Aμ |Wλ |Ιλ |Βc |Ξa |
               Jk |Πϑ |Ιt |Εψ |Hε |Ωϑ |Εη |Ie |Κω |Yc |Iβ |Ου |Hg |Θr |Nn |Uμ |Ζv |Ζχ |Jρ |Pο |Ng |Be |Δv |Fζ |Ρe |Qe |Cq |Κf |Θλ |Tϑ |Ξq |Me |Βq |Oα |Θc |Qr |Δt |Dm |Yu |Ru |Σh |Λr |Yy |Εε |Μχ |Mφ |Δδ |Kφ |Cγ |Ζσ |Iω |Au |Wb |Κc |Πq |Ωω |Pυ |Γn |Nγ |Cv |Βχ |Φg |Gο |Ug |Kο |Βκ |Wμ |Hτ |Hχ |Ue |Οw |Sμ |Sm |Υω |Yb |Χa |Ιi |Κν |Πu |Κψ |Uτ |Lβ |Fj |Pn |Εf |Τσ |Qε |Ψo |Λρ |Oϑ |Πν |Ts |Ηο |Μρ |Ff |Ψβ |Ne |Nκ |Bλ |Bσ |Mx |Πp |Υσ |Ιn |Αz |Fz |Ηa |Uν |Mζ |Δϑ |Yι |Ζe |Ψα |Tο |Βg |Lπ |Ζf |Αλ |Em |Θh |Gπ |Γω |Kω |Tξ |Σn |So |Im |Φυ |Ξb |Ii |Λι |Xz |Kδ |Μω |Uυ |Wf |Χb |Sλ |Lγ |Οη |Ιs |Xβ |Pκ |Bc |Ιp |Od |Αn |Va |Tω |Ζw |Ιτ |Θε |Ρi |Gι |Τh |Υx |Nτ |Δη |Εφ |Kx |Xa |Gν |Ft |Yt |Qd |Gσ |Ξυ |Εs |Nσ |Νc |Λj |Υu |Ρc |Ψξ |Δm |Qβ |Μu |Υb |Nk |Ωτ |Κr |Δd |Iλ |Πa |Ωρ |Χν |Μh |Jξ |Μμ |Fc |Iφ |Zr |Ux |Φb |Πo |Gd |Eζ |Αα |Νν |Λz |Vη |Pψ |Ωf |Lρ |Cb |Ν |Α |Χ |Ω |Zτ |Τκ |Αε |Bβ |Uι |Fi |Ui |Βx |Ωq |Βp |Λh |Uu |Ωw |Xp |Ζβ |Λτ
 | N2012 deriving(Enum); instance Show Counter where show = show . fromEnum
```

Comment: I'm afraid this compiles just fine modified, although an exception is thrown at *runtime*.

Comment: @JeffBurdges: sure, I take this to be included in "and will not cause it to crash".

Comment: For the `a=map(head.show.length)[[a,a],[],[a],[a,a]]` solution, insert `a` between `[]`. I really like this post, though! Very clever solutions.

Comment: I've verified that all 5825 variations of your 29-character program (replacing or inserting ASCII characters 32-126) work as expected. [Here's the test script I used](https://gist.github.com/1557768). It can easily be tweaked to test other programs, including other languages. Warning: It took almost 1 hour to run on my laptop :)

Comment: Couldn't you make it two characters less by using `x` instead of `xx`?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: sure, but it wouldn't be modification-safe anymore.

Comment: `[a]` -> `[]` in the 64-char solution

Comment: on this solution `(\l@(_:_:t:[])->t:l)['0'..'2']` if you would change `@` to a space the solution would be still be syntactically valid (and in fact will have a type of `Num a=>[a]->[a]`) but would not be a string of "2012".

Comment: this also disqualifies your first solution :( although note this doesn't change the full program solutions as there is no Function Show instance :)

Comment: on the 72 solution you could also write `a=[[a,a,a],[a],[a,a],[a,a,a]]>>=show.length.init` which is shorter - but i'm not sure if it's unmodifiable...

Answer (score 14):

### JavaScript

I believe this is runtime error proof, any single change should either result in a compile error or a single alert saying 2012.

Edit: Code would make a runtime error on something like `if("alert(2012 "==r)`, I moved the try section to deal with it.

Edit: Nice one Vilx-, but fixable :-) Now there is a bracket mismatch for inserting that semicolon.

Edit: But then a comma could do the same thing as the semicolon, that is a host of options, I think I have fixed it, but there is an awful lot of code now.

Edit: Simplified a bit.

Edit: One more in an infinite series of bugfixes.

Edit: This kinda feels more long and complicated than bulletproof, but it should at least take care of `~eval` and `!eval`.

```
var q="alert(2012 "
var p=1
try{
    if("alert(2012 "==q){
        if(eval(((p=5,q+")")||alert(2012)))){
            if(p!==5){
                alert(2012)
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        alert(2012)
    }
}
catch(e){
    alert(2012)
}
```

Comment: Wow that's impressive. I spent a few minutes trying to break it but I couldn't, congratulations, but why the `||alert(2012)`?

Comment: Because for instance `q-")"` returns `NaN`, which eval convert to `"NaN"` before evaling it, which simply turns it back to `NaN`. Strange thing to do, but technically legit, so that doesn't invoke the catch.

Comment: Same thing as the C solution - insert a `;` between `eval` and `(`.

Comment: For the comment readers, the semicolon vulnerability is fixed, I believe the code to be clean now.

Comment: Not sure if this counts or not, but putting a `~` in front of the `eval` causes it to echo `2012` **twice** instead of once.  Not sure if that disobeys the rules or not :P

Comment: Adding a semicolon after `else` also alerts "2012" twice :P

Comment: Adding a `!` after `eval(` breaks it.

Comment: Why the `try` while modified code can error?

Answer (score 14):

### Perl, 49 chars

```
  do{
use strict;$_=2012;;2012==$_&&0-print||die}
```

Based on [J B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4511/3191), but this one **actually satisfies the spec**.  An exhaustive check indicates that every one-character deletion, insertion or replacement either leaves the output unchanged or causes the program to crash when run (as indicated by a non-zero return value and output to stderr), at least as long as insertions and replacements are restricted to printable ASCII characters.

(Without the restriction, the task is impossible in Perl: [a little-known feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) of the Perl parser is that it stops when it encounters a Ctrl-D or a Ctrl-Z character, so inserting either of those in front of any file turns it into a valid Perl program that does nothing.)

**Edit:** Shaved off one more char by replacing `1==print` with `0-print`.

Comment: Breaks with Perl 5.28 where `print` starts returning `'true'` instead of 1 :-P

Comment: @JB: Well, you can downvote it when that happens. :)  (For the benefit of other readers, this is a joke.  As far as I know, there are no plans to change the return value of `print` in any version of Perl 5, even if it isn't [explicitly documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html).)

Answer (score 14):

### Brainfuck

I am trying to convince myself that this is possible, and I am fairly certain I may have stretched it a bit too far. I have made a few assumptions about my environment:

1. An infinite loop is considered a 'crash'. A similar condition could possibly be achieved by decrementing past zero or to the left of memory location zero in certain interpreters. Many interpreters are difficult to crash at runtime. I avoid the halting problem by using only the simplest, most obvious infinite loop.
2. Unmatched square braces are considered a compile error.
3. This will only work in an environment where the program's output is piped back to it's own input. I use that to verify that it did indeed output '2012'. This is the only way I could get around simply deleting one of the output characters.

Unfortunately, if you get any stricter I fear this will be impossible. Here is my solution:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
.--.+.+.
,--------------------------------------------------[]
,------------------------------------------------[]
,-------------------------------------------------[]
,--------------------------------------------------[]
,[]EOF = 0
```

Basically, you can change the output code, or the verification code, but not both. One of them is guaranteed to work. If one of them doesn't it will 'crash'.

Comment: would you have preferred he used whitespace instead?

Comment: Fail if adding `.` after any `]`. You can claim `.` don't output 0 to resolve

Answer (score 7):

### Python2

```
import sys;xx='2012';(
1/(sys.stdout.write(xx=='2012' and xx or 2012)==None))
```

I had to change [Ray's test script](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9191/95) slightly to test this as the stdout redirect was breaking it. Passing empty dicts to exec avoids polluting the namespace

```
exec(prog, {}, {})
```

Comment: Great! You make it!

Answer (score 6):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 44 + 3 = 47 bytes [Non-Competing]

This uses Brain-Flak's `-A` flag and outputs the characters `2012` to STDOUT

```
((((((((()()()){}){}){}()){})[()])[()])()())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BA5ogqFldC0EQZrSGZiyEAEv@//9f1xEA)

## Alternative, 50 bytes

```
(((((()()()()){}){}){}){})({({}[()])}{}[()()()()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68BBpoQqFldi0Aa1RrVtdEamrGatWAaAmM1//8HAA)

### Explanation

Any single character modification to either of the codes above will cause the program to error.

Comment: Ha! The right language for the challenge.

Answer (score 6):

## [Sisi](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Sisi), non-competing

Finally I think I found one of my languages that works. It's horrendously long, and the language is newer than the question, but it still feels like an accomplishment.

```
1 set xx 2012
2 set y xx=2012
3 jumpif y 55
4 set xx 2012
828 set x xx
829 set ax xx
830 set xa xx
831 set axx xx
832 set xax xx
833 set xxa xx
834 set bx xx
835 set xb xx
836 set bxx xx
837 set xbx xx
838 set xxb xx
839 set cx xx
840 set xc xx
841 set cxx xx
842 set xcx xx
843 set xxc xx
844 set dx xx
845 set xd xx
846 set dxx xx
847 set xdx xx
848 set xxd xx
849 set ex xx
850 set xe xx
851 set exx xx
852 set xex xx
853 set xxe xx
854 set fx xx
855 set xf xx
856 set fxx xx
857 set xfx xx
858 set xxf xx
859 set gx xx
860 set xg xx
861 set gxx xx
862 set xgx xx
863 set xxg xx
864 set hx xx
865 set xh xx
866 set hxx xx
867 set xhx xx
868 set xxh xx
869 set ix xx
870 set xi xx
871 set ixx xx
872 set xix xx
873 set xxi xx
874 set jx xx
875 set xj xx
876 set jxx xx
877 set xjx xx
878 set xxj xx
879 set kx xx
880 set xk xx
881 set kxx xx
882 set xkx xx
883 set xxk xx
884 set lx xx
885 set xl xx
886 set lxx xx
887 set xlx xx
888 set xxl xx
889 set mx xx
890 set xm xx
891 set mxx xx
892 set xmx xx
893 set xxm xx
894 set nx xx
895 set xn xx
896 set nxx xx
897 set xnx xx
898 set xxn xx
899 set ox xx
900 set xo xx
901 set oxx xx
902 set xox xx
903 set xxo xx
904 set px xx
905 set xp xx
906 set pxx xx
907 set xpx xx
908 set xxp xx
909 set qx xx
910 set xq xx
911 set qxx xx
912 set xqx xx
913 set xxq xx
914 set rx xx
915 set xr xx
916 set rxx xx
917 set xrx xx
918 set xxr xx
919 set sx xx
920 set xs xx
921 set sxx xx
922 set xsx xx
923 set xxs xx
924 set tx xx
925 set xt xx
926 set txx xx
927 set xtx xx
928 set xxt xx
929 set ux xx
930 set xu xx
931 set uxx xx
932 set xux xx
933 set xxu xx
934 set vx xx
935 set xv xx
936 set vxx xx
937 set xvx xx
938 set xxv xx
939 set wx xx
940 set xw xx
941 set wxx xx
942 set xwx xx
943 set xxw xx
944 set yx xx
945 set xy xx
946 set yxx xx
947 set xyx xx
948 set xxy xx
949 set zx xx
950 set xz xx
951 set zxx xx
952 set xzx xx
953 set xxz xx
954 set xxx xx
955 print xx
```

#### About Sisi

Sisi is a toy language inspired by assembly and QBasic. It is good for this challenge because its syntax is extremely limited.

- It has only four commands: `set`, `print`, `jump`, and `jumpif`.
- All commands have fixed arity.
- All lines must have line numbers, which are strictly increasing.
- Expressions are only allowed in `set` statements. They can only contain (at most) one operation, which must be binary. In particular: changing `print xx` to `print -xx` is a syntax error.
- Variable names must be composed of lowercase letters.
- Most importantly: there is *no comment syntax*!

#### The program

The core of the program is this part:

```
1 set xx 2012
2 set y xx=2012
3 jumpif y 55
4 set xx 2012
955 print xx
```

We store `2012` in `xx`, then test whether that was successful and store the test result in `y`. If `y` is truthy, jump to line 55. (Jumps to nonexistent line numbers simply fast-forward to the next line.)

#### Radiation hardening

- If the assignment in line 1 is modified, then `y` is falsey, the jump doesn't happen, and line 4 sets `xx` to 2012.
- If the assignment in line 2 or the jump condition in line 3 is modified, we don't care: `xx` will get set to 2012 whether we take the jump or not.
- The jump target in line 3 can be changed to as small as 5 or as large as 955. Any possible modification gets it to the `print` on line 955 sooner or later. It isn't possible with one modification to jump backwards (creating a loop) or past the end of the program.
- If the assignment in line 4 is modified, we don't care: line 1's assignment will be correct and we will jump past line 4.
- If line 955 is modified, we may have a problem. The one unfortunate thing about Sisi is that uninitialized variables default to `0`, so a modification like `print ax` isn't an error. The ugly but effective solution is lines 828-954, which assign 2012 to every possible variable with an edit distance of 1 from `xx`. This ensures that any modification to the final `print xx` will still print 2012.
- If a line number is modified, either: 1) it will be out of order and be a syntax error, or 2) it won't affect the program flow. The main modification we might be worried about--changing line 4 to 94, thereby inserting it after the jump to 55--doesn't matter because all it does is assign 2012 to `xx` again.

Comment: Good one! I can't think of a way to circumvent this. "A" for effort from me, that's for sure! :)

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL 2012, 55

```
DECLARE @n CHAR(4)='2012'PRINT IIF(@n='2012',@n,'2012')
```

Comment: What SQL dialect is this? Looks like Transact-SQL (aka SQL Server), but it has invalid syntax for that.

Comment: @Vilx-: I tested it in SQL Server 2008 myself when I was trying to break it, and it worked just fine.

Comment: @mellamokb - That's odd. It's exactly what I did, and it complained that you cannot assign a default value to variable (you need a separate SET statement), and there is no IIF (only CASE).

Comment: @Vilx-: Ah, you are correct.  I realize now I was actually testing on SQL Azure.  With SQL Server 2008 I get those same errors as you.  However, it seems to work fine in SQL Server 2012/Azure.  Here's a demo with SQL 2012: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/27

Comment: OK, congratulations, I can't find any obvious ways of breaking this! :) That's not to say there aren't any. ;)

Comment: Note: linked fiddle now gives an error, possibly because SQLfiddle is using SQL Server 2014 and doesn't offer 2012 anymore.

Answer (score 2):

### **Ruby 1.9** - 43 chars

```
qq=[:p,2012]
b if qq!=[:p,2012]
send(
*qq)
```

Not tested, so break away.

Answer (score 2):

**Excel, 14 characters** (cheating slightly):

```
{=2012} (in a 2x1 array with one cell hidden)
```

Any valid change to the array will affect the contents of both cells, and attempting to change just one cell triggers an error message.

Of course, this breaks down if you take the view that it's really only one formula, as opposed to 2 formulas that are constrained to be identical.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7

```java
class M{
  static String c(){
    String a = "2012",
           b = "2012";
    return a.equals(b)           // 1
            ? a                  // 2
            : a.equals("2012")   // 3
               ? a               // 4
               : b;              // 5
  }

  public static void main(String[]a){
    System.out.print(c());
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. Without changing anything it will take the following path: 1 → 2 (and it will return `a`'s value of `2012`).
2. If the content of String `a` is modified in any way it will take the following path: 1 → 3 → 5 (and it will return `b`'s unchanged value of `2012`).
3. If the content of String `b` is modified in any way it will take the following path: 1 → 3 → 4 (and it will return `a`'s unchanged value of `2012`).
4. If `a.equals(b)` on @1 is modified to `a.equals(a)`, `b.equals(b)`, or `!a.equals(b)` it will still take the same following path: 1 → 2 (and it will return `a`'s unchanged value of `2012`).
5. If `a` on @2 is changed to `b` it will still take the following path: 1 → 2 (and it will return `b`'s unchanged value of `2012`).
6. If either `a` or `b` is changed to the opposite on the lines 3, 4 or 5 it will still take the following path: 1 → 2 (and it will return `a`'s unchanged value of `2012`)
7. If the content of the String on @3 is modified in any way it will still take the following path: 1 → 2 (and it will return `a`'s unchanged value of `2012`)
8. Changing `M` in `class M` or `a` in `main(String[]a)` to another valid character can be done without any changes to the functionality of the code.
9. Any other change will result in a Compile-error (excluding some of the enters/whitespaces, which can be removed/added).

[Try all these modifications here, to verify they all still print 2012.](https://tio.run/##rZMxb4MwEIX3/AonE0gtajMWVRXeGFiablWHMzapU2Kn2CBVEb@dkgCJBAm1SxgA4yd/9453GyjgfkO/qipOQSkUARf7GUK7nKQ8RkqDrh@F5BRt6y1npTMu1u8fCNyDDKHVj9Js68lce7t6S6fCoSyBPNUR05@SOq7rXxOq42FBJClPODOQYhNpwjOlw6STvsnASo0N1KEoWKaNynhlOs8EDkUtgHGLLJaCGpfSyRtAYAGwL6nnt5zVtzYaTSBQ75@j7tq3@/C8WD48Lhd3pH3xs2MVCDz2nUOqHOK@wNNp1YgOn4hfDmiD4Axpt4bhMdjJ2mTYpfDa9RGm0LAhjUzwdg6TYUbmUzrZD7tdIolxSC4Nr33@iR2tP/vTpw3@pOGb0ciot2Z5nrp/00wa2c@kJWx@xVtZVb8)

If you can find any way to break it following OP's rules I'd love to know, so I can think of something to fix it.
Unlike most similar questions where a single char is modified, this question allows the basic structure of the programming language in question to be intact, so Java can finally <s>compete in one</s> enter one (let's face it, Java will -almost- never win anything on this SE xD).

Comment: What is a negative sign is inserted in path 4 before the `a`? Will the program still output 2012, or will it output -2012?

Comment: @KritixiLithos It's a String, so you can't insert a `-` before the `a` or `b`. [Here is a screenshot of the Compile error.](https://s28.postimg.org/pbakznwn1/String_error.png)

Answer (score 2):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 396 bytes

```
2012 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.2012 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology: w 1 r 3 l 2 l 3 l 2 r.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner: w 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery: n 3 r 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office: n 1 l 1 r.
```

Formatted for humans, that's:

```
2012 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
2012 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: w 1 r 3 l 2 l 3 l 2 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.
Go to Equal's Corner: w 1 l.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: n 3 r 1 r 1 r.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: n 1 l 1 r.
```

From reading other answers, the solution seems to be to pick a fragile language, set the value, check the value, print the value.

Answer (score 1):

### Tcl, 55 chars.

```
if {$a=={puts 2012}} [set a {puts 2012}] {
puts 2012
#}
```

Check if the code is unmodified, then execute it, or print `2012`.
I consider accessing a undefined variable as syntax error.

## Tcl, 138 Characters

```
set a {set a {$a};if {\$a=={$a}} {puts 2012}};if {[info ex a]&&$a=={set a {$a};if {\$a=={$a}} {puts 2012}}} [subst -noc $a] {
puts 2012
#}
```

Ok, this is a quine variant: either the code is unmodified, then execute it, or simply print `2012`

The last line is a little bit special: It is a comment, but the `}` closes the brace.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 24

this is a simple fix to @Dr.belisarius [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4575/62269) *(unfortunately, I can't add comments yet*)

```
2012//.Except@2012->2012
```

Changing Replace (`/.`) to RepeatedReplace (`//.`) fixes the problem @Dillon found, since `///` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC

```
OPTION STRICT
VAR A$=@2012
GOTO A$@2012
IF SHIFT(A$)THEN VAR B
?A$VAR C
B=C
```

First, we enable strict mode. This forces you to declare all variables before using them, and prevents things like changing ?A$ to ?B$.

Next, a string variable called "A$" is created, and the value is set to "@2012". To make sure the value of A$ hasn't been messed with, the program will try to jump to a label, and the only label in the program is @2012.

Now, A$ is definitely "@2012", but before printing it, the @ needs to be removed. SHIFT() removes the first item in a string or array (just like pop(), but from the other end).
To discard the value returned by SHIFT, it is passed to an IF/THEN block, which does nothing.
Just in case someone tries to comment out that line, we declare a variable "B", which is used later. If the VAR is commented out, the last line will throw an Undefined variable error.

Now, A$ is printed, and there's another VAR to prevent comments.
The final line just makes sure the variables B and C have both been declared.

Comment: OK... I don't know anything about SmileBASIC, so this is purely a guess: `?-A$VAR C` - could this output `-2012`?

Comment: That won't work because A$ is a string.

Comment: Wait, I have an idea! What about: `?B$VAR C`?  :)

Comment: That will trigger an error because "B$" hasn't been declared.

Answer (score 1):

## Sinclair ZX81/Timex TS1000/1500 BASIC, 54 tokenized BASIC bytes used

```
 1 LET A$="2012"
 2 PRINT "2012" AND A$="2012";"2012" AND A$<>"2012"
```

Regardless of the value in `A$` 2012 is still shown on the screen. I have used string literals because it's faster for writing to the screen (in BASIC at least) and also saves BASIC bytes. So `A$` can contain any string value possible on the ZX81 tokenized "one-touch" entry system.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 105 bytes

```
fn main(){use std::io::{Write,stdout};stdout().write_all({let a=b"2012";if a==b"2012"{a}else{b"2012"}});}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NchBCoAgEEDRq4grhYhyqXSOlmE0gWAJOdJimLNbUa0@7x8lY63rLjYfdqWpZBAZF2tDspbGIyA0t1NBdm@Vbs9nTz5GRRFQ@GGWpuuNdGG98Ys8Q8xAH5m141ov)

Most of the length comes from writing directly to stdout vs using the `print!` macro. Unfortunately, the format string in `print!("{}", x);` can be easily modified and is checked at compile time so you can't pass in the value as a string directly.

Comment: I don't know any Rust, so this looks solid. One question - the place where it goes `{a}` - can't something be done with that? Like `{!a}` or `{~a}` or something? I'm just shooting blind here, but perhaps there's some operator that can be used on a string?

Comment: @Vilx- Neither of those operators are valid in that location. `a`'s type is `&[u8]` (which is a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html)) and `write_all` is expecting a `&[u8]` so it's not really possible with a single character change to modify `a` in that location without causing a compiler error, as far as I can tell at least.

Answer (score 1):

## Lenguage, 176848577745260300319721504 bytes

Not really fun though.

No modification/edit a byte: [`----------[+>+++++<]>.--.+.+.+`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fFw6ite20QcAm1k5PV1dPGwT//wcA)

Add a byte: [`----------[+>+++++<]>.--.+.+.-`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fFw6ite20QcAm1k5PV1dPGwh1//8HAA)

Remove a byte: [`----------[+>+++++<]>.--.+.+<]`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fFw6ite20QcAm1k5PV1dPWw/I@v8fAA)

## JavaScript, 48 bytes

```javascript
q="e=alert(2012)"
q=="e=alert(2012)"?eval(q)+e:w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifmJNaVGJbUJSZV/K/0FYp1RYsoGFkYGikqcRVaIsuZJ9alpijUaipnWpV/v8/AA)

Comment: This language almost feels like cheating here. :D

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 65

```
import Data.List
nub$filter(\x->x==2012||x==2012)([2012]++[2012])
```

### Perl, 84

```
use strict;use English;$ARG=
2032;s/.*/2012/unless$ARG eq 2012;$SUBSEP=2012;print;
```

Failed approach :

```
use strict;use English;"2012 2012"=~
/2012|2012|2012/;print$MATCH||$MATCH;
```

Comment: You Perl solution can be broken by replacing the first `$&` with something like `$0`.

Comment: And the Haskell one breaks if you replace the comma with a plus sign. Valiant attempt though.

Comment: I think `nub$filter(\x->x==2012||x==2012)(2012:[2012])` might be safe for the Haskell solution.

Comment: I forgot the `use English` in perl, that'll fix it.  I think several fixes work for Haskell, including switching to strings.

Comment: Replacing the first `$MATCH` with `*MATCH` gives the output `*main::&`.

Comment: Does use strict even count as compile time in Perl?  I'd vote no myself.

Comment: The Perl solution is still pretty fragile. Some ways to break it (found while testing [my own answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4512/3191)) include replacing `print` with `*rint`, `prin:`, `p:int` or `#rint`,  prepending `=` to the first line, or even replacing `s/.*/` with `s/./` or `y/.*/` (which would be fixed by initializing `$ARG` to `2012` to begin with).  Also, your `$SUBSEP` trick still doesn't protect against inserting a `*` before the final semicolon, but a much easier solution is to just remove that unnecessary semicolon.

Comment: Ahh, thanks!  Perl isn't the optimal language for this one I guess.  lol

Comment: Indeed, it's too flexible.  I'd actually half convinced myself that a correct Perl solution was impossible before I hit upon the trick of testing the return value of `print` (which is not explicitly documented, but hey, this is code golf).

Answer (score 0):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 83 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(){var q="2012";System.Console.Write(q=="2012"?q:"2012");}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS5O/v8/OSexuFghoLq4JLEkM1mhLD8zRcE3MTNPQ7M6uLK4JDVXzzk/rzg/J1UvvCizJFVDycjA0EjJ1hZC20MoKwilaV1b@/8/AA)

Comment: Aaand it fails. Should output `2012`, not `2014`. XD But, yes, the approach seems to be valid. I cannot think of a way to break it.

Comment: I feel stupid now

Comment: Aaand this version fails because I can do `"2012"=="2012"?"2014":"2012"`. You need the `var`. :)

Comment: Well I should probably stop trying to make this shorter then xD