# Resistent counter

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, source-layout, counting

You just have to ouput **exactly** all the numbers from 1 to 10 separated by spaces.

Your programme should work all the times even if a random character is deleted before compiling/interpreting.

This is code-golf so shortest code in bytes win!

Comment: What is the winning criteria ?

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11383/8478)

Comment: @Optimizer codegolf, sorry if I forgot to mention it.

Comment: This is really tough in CJam at least ..

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of [Fault-Tolerant Hello World](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11383/20260). The conditions are same, and the required output is `"0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"` rather than `"Hello world"`. I understand that this is code golf and in theory allows a loop strategy (though I suspect it's impractical compared to hardcoding the string), so you might consider it sufficiently different. Still, I consider the core idea too similar to justify another such question.

Comment: Is it alright if it gives an error after it prints the numbers when some of the chars are removed or prints garbage after the numbers?

Comment: @xnor I think that this is fairly different. Only the Befunge answer can be reused here (not sure about the Perl one) . Plus, in this question, you cannot have an answer with a fault. It *should* have score 0 as per the other question. All answers of this question can be used into the other one, though.

Comment: @xnor That question wasn't code-golf but code-challenge. It's related but not duplicate imo. Looping is quite shorter for me in fish. (Looping might even add some resistant in some cases. Might not.) Idk though how viable complete resistance is in other languages.