# How short can you get?

Tags: code-challenge, kolmogorov-complexity, radiation-hardening

You are to write a program that, when given an integer between 1 and 5 (or 0 and 4 if you wish to use 0-indexing), outputs one of `Code`, `Golf`, `and`, `Coding` or `Challenges`. Each input can map to any of the five outputs. However, the mapping must be one to one (each input goes to a different output) and consistent when running the program multiple times.

For example, `1 -> Coding`, `2 -> Golf`, `3 -> and`, `4 -> Code` and `5 -> Challenges` is a perfectly acceptable mapping. The capitalisation and spelling of the outputs must match, but leading and trailing whitespace is perfectly acceptable.

Rather than [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), we will use a different scoring system (lets use `abcdef` as an example program):

- If your program works **whenever any single (\$1\$) character is removed**, your score is \$1\$.

  - So `bcdef`, `acdef`, `abdef`, `abcef`, `abcdf` and `abcde` should **all** work as program on their own
  - By "work", I mean that the program still fulfils the first two paragraphs of this challenge spec. The 5 possible inputs may be different to the unaltered program, and to each of the other altered programs, so long as they meet the rules above.
- If your program **still works whenever any pair (\$2\$) of consecutive characters are removed**, your score is \$2\$

  - So, to qualify for a score of \$2\$, `abcd`, `abcf`, `abef`, `adef` and `cdef` must all work according to the challenge spec
- And so on. If your program still works whenever any subset of length \$n\$ of consecutive characters is removed from it, your score is \$n\$.

The program with the largest \$n\$ wins. In order to compete, all programs must have a score of at least \$1\$. Your program must work for *all* \$i \le n\$ in order to qualify for a score of \$n\$. So in order to score \$5\$, your program must also score \$1, 2, 3\$ and \$4\$.

[This](https://tio.run/##XZCxbsMwDERn@yu4SWrtoEa3oukndOloeDCSc6LApgRFAZKvd0XZadqOvOM9Huhv8ej4dZ59cIfQT7QlpdQ7OCLQXTsi4CPJZTm4QOcIT5Yp9HyAbioawXpdNeatLHywHLX62rkA2qoqJ0xZSNg@kr9jVC/YZ2qEUOycv6Uq7UtHT3/4ybO8x1VM26VJoKcHNFPqlbKsbnrvwXudh7ZuunxljaIijJgEAL5MCH3Ez7GFMRDEzvGs5HYtutTh0zFEwnjGf0@4SVq/oTYnZ1kPdkyf1ZKrSHaNMfePmXn@Bg) is a Python program which will output all the possible alterations to your original program, along with the score they're worth.

Comment: Must we write a full program, or is a function acceptable?

Comment: @RobinRyder As per default, either a full program or function is acceptable

Comment: It's worth an ask, but would the downvoter mind explaining their vote? I can only improve, and any and all feedback would help me do that.

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but are you sure the scoring system can't be abused for an infinite score? (in Lenguage, a + is, as far as I remember, decremented into ], so it won't work, but most other length encodings work; I'm trying to produce an arbitrarily extendable Befunge solution now)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## 8086 machine code (MS-DOS .COM), score 26 402

The file is 52 947 bytes long. The length was a product of what produced benign instruction sleds, and the maximum file size for .COM files (65 280 bytes -- 65 264 in case an interrupt happens before you can stop it).

Here in binary form, with repeating lines snipped out for obvious reasons:

```
00000000 : E9 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 : .ggggggggggggggg
00000010 : 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 67 : gggggggggggggggg
    <...>
00006720 : 67 67 67 67 67 90 D1 EE AD 93 AC E8 00 00 5A 2C : ggggg.........Z,
00006730 : 30 01 C2 3C 04 75 03 83 C2 02 D1 E0 D1 E0 01 C2 : 0..<.u..........
00006740 : 83 C2 1B B4 09 CD 21 CD 20 43 6F 64 65 24 47 6F : ......!. Code$Go
00006750 : 6C 66 24 61 6E 64 24 24 43 6F 64 69 6E 67 24 43 : lf$and$$Coding$C
00006760 : 68 61 6C 6C 65 6E 67 65 73 24 EB 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F : hallenges$......
00006770 : 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F : ................
    <...>
0000CE80 : 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F 9F D1 : ................
0000CE90 : EE AD 93 AC E8 00 00 5A 2C 30 01 C2 3C 04 75 03 : .......Z,0..<.u.
0000CEA0 : 83 C2 02 D1 E0 D1 E0 01 C2 83 C2 1B B4 09 CD 21 : ...............!
0000CEB0 : CD 20 43 6F 64 65 24 47 6F 6C 66 24 61 6E 64 24 : . Code$Golf$and$
0000CEC0 : 24 43 6F 64 69 6E 67 24 43 68 61 6C 6C 65 6E 67 : $Coding$Challeng
0000CED0 : 65 73 24                                        : es$
```

In readable form:

```
org 0x100
cpu 8086

SLED_LEN    equ (0x6767 - (part1_end - part1) + 2)

db 0xe9
times SLED_LEN db 0x67

part1:
    nop
    shr si, 1       ; SI = 0x80
    lodsw           ; SI = 0x82
    xchg bx, ax     ; AX = 0
    lodsb           ; AL = first character of command line argument

    ; Load DX with IP, since we only know our strings' relative position
    call near .nextline
.nextline:
    pop dx

    sub al, '0'
    add dx, ax
    cmp al, 4
    jne .skip
    add dx, 2

.skip:
    shl ax, 1
    shl ax, 1
    add dx, ax

    add dx, 0x1b
    mov ah, 0x09
    int 0x21
    int 0x20

p1_msg0 db "Code$"
p1_msg1 db "Golf$"
p1_msg2 db "and$$"
p1_msg3 db "Coding$"
p1_msg4 db "Challenges$"

part1_end:

part2:
    db 0xeb
    times SLED_LEN db 0x9f

    shr si, 1       ; SI = 0x80
    lodsw           ; SI = 0x82
    xchg bx, ax     ; AX = 0
    lodsb           ; AL = first character of command line argument

    ; Load DX with IP, since we only know our strings' relative position
    call near .nextline
.nextline:
    pop dx

    sub al, '0'
    add dx, ax
    cmp al, 4
    jne .skip
    add dx, 2

.skip:
    shl ax, 1
    shl ax, 1
    add dx, ax

    add dx, 0x1b
    mov ah, 0x09
    int 0x21
    int 0x20

p2_msg0 db "Code$"
p2_msg1 db "Golf$"
p2_msg2 db "and$$"
p2_msg3 db "Coding$"
p2_msg4 db "Challenges$"
```

## Rundown

This is a slightly adapted variation on a [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/191375/75886) of mine.

The active part is duplicated so that there is always one untouched by radiation. We select the healthy version by way of jumps. Each jump is a near jump, and so is only three bytes long, where two last bytes are the displacement (i.e. distance to jump, with sign determining direction). This displacement is replicated over and over, forming a long NOP sled of sorts.

We can divide the code into four parts which could be irradiated: jump 1, code 1, jump 2, and code 2. The idea is to make sure a clean code part is always used. If one of the code parts is irradiated, the other must be chosen, but if one of the jumps is irradiated, both code parts will be clean, so it will not matter which one is chosen.

The reason for having two jump parts is to detect irradiation in the first part by jumping over it. If the first code part is irradiated, it means we will arrive off mark, somewhere in the second NOP sled. If we make sure that such a botched landing selects code 2, and a proper landing selects code 1, we're golden.

For both jumps, we duplicate the displacement word, making each jump part one opcode followed by a massive repetition of the displacement. This ensures that irradiation somewhere in the sled will still make the jump valid, as long as at least two bytes of the sled remains. Irradiation in the first byte will stop the jump from happening at all, since the following sled will form a completely different instruction.

Take the first jump:

```
E9 67 67 67 67 ...      jmp +0x6767 / dw 0x6767 ...
```

If either of the `0x67` bytes are removed, it will still jump to the same place, as long as at least one word remains. If the `0xE9` byte is removed, we will instead end up with

```
67 67 67 67...
```

each of which is a address-size override prefix. The CPU will gladly chomp them all down, and then we fall through to code 1, which must be clean, since the damage was in jump 1.

If the jump is taken, we land at the second jump:

```
EB 9F 9F 9F 9F ...       jmp -0x61 / db 0x9f
```

If this byte sequence is intact, and we land right on the mark, that means that code 1 was clean, and this instruction jumps back to that part. The replicated displacement byte guarantees this, even if it is one of these displacement bytes that were damaged.

The astute reader will notice that this instruction jumps too far back, but that's alright, since if we hit the jump, then part1's NOP sled must be wholly intact, making a slightly longer jump backwards okay.

If we either land off the mark (because of a damaged code 1 or jump 1) or the `0xEB` byte is the damaged one, the remaining bytes will also here be benign:

```
9F 9F 9F 9F ...          lahf / lahf
```

Whichever the case, if we end up executing that sled of instructions, we know that either jump 1, code 1, or jump 2 were irradiated, which makes a fall-through to code 2 safe.

### Testing

Testing proved problematic. I've done some tests on certain corner-cases and a few random ones, but I have to find a better way for exhaustive testing. It should not be a problem up to the above-mentioned score.

The following program was used to automatically create all versions of the .COM file for a certain gap size. It also creates a BAT file that can be run in the target environment, which runs each irradiated binary, and pipes their outputs to separate text files. Comparing the output files to validate is easy enough, but DOSBox does not have `fc`, so it was not added to the BAT file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fin, *fout, *fbat;
    int fsize;
    char *data;
    int gapsize = 1;

    if (!(fin = fopen(argv[1], "rb")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file \"%s\".\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!(fbat = fopen("tester.bat", "w")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create BAT test file.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    if (argc > 2)
    {
        gapsize = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fin);
    fseek(fin, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    if (!(data = malloc(fsize)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory.\n");
        exit(3);
    }

    fread(data, 1, fsize, fin);

    fprintf(fbat, "@echo off\n");

    for (int i = 0; i <= fsize - gapsize; i++)
    {
        char fname[512];

        sprintf(fname, "%06d.com", i);

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            fprintf(fbat, "%s %d >> %06d.txt\n", fname, j, i);

        fout = fopen(fname, "wb");

        fwrite(data, 1, i, fout);
        fwrite(data + i + gapsize, 1, fsize - i - gapsize, fout);

        fclose(fout);
    }

    free(data);
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fbat);
}
```